# How do I make a QuerySet in Django to see if a name in the database is a substring of my query string?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-mysql

As the title mentions, I am working in Django and trying to make a QuerySet to return all "Customer" models that have a name value that is a substring of my query_string.

I want something like this:

```
Customer.objects.filter(firstName__icontains=query_string)
```

But in reverse:

```
Customer.objects.filter(query_string__icontains=firstName)
```

Except that obviously doesn't work.

I am struggling to find any information on how I would go about this.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit***
My expected input will be in Japanese - Kana and Kanji　かな、カナ、漢字

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781832/django-how-to-use-filter-to-check-if-string-field-is-contained-in-parameter

Comment: I thought about doing something similar to that, but unfortunately the site I am making is in Japanese. Japanese names are usually searched without any spaces between the names, making that solution unusable for me. :/ Unless of course I split the search bar into two separate inputs - but I am trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: use the second answer not the selected one :D

Comment: I attempted the second one as well. I am getting the same error I got in Brad 's answer "Cannot resolve keyword query_string into field."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the answers!
I was able to solve my problem by building off of @brad's answer.

I took his approach of defining a custom lookup. It pretty much looks like his, but I configured it for MySQL.

```
class LowerContainedBy(Lookup):
lookup_name = 'icontained_by'

def as_mysql(self, compiler, connection):
    lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
    rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
    params = lhs_params + rhs_params
    return  "LOWER({0}) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%%',{1},'%%'))".format(lhs, rhs), params

Field.register_lookup(LowerContainedBy)
```

(I also noticed the rhs and lhs was flipped in his answer so keep that in mind!)

And finally by implementing the new lookup like so:

```
searchResults = Customer.objects.filter(firstName__icontained_by=search_string).exclude(contract='').order_by('-dateCreated')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a [custom lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/lookups/#lookup-reference). This one below is Postgres specific:

```
class LowerContainedBy(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'icontained_by'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return f"LOWER({rhs}) LIKE '%%' || LOWER({lhs}) || '%%'", params

CharField.register_lookup(LowerContainedBy)
```

Then you can do:

```
Customer.objects.filter(firstName__icontained_by=query_string)
```

Comment: Struggling to get this one to work.. when I put "query_string" on the left hand side I get a "Cannot resolve keyword" error.

Comment: Sorry, my copy_and_paste error, I'll edit to be correct

Comment: I think your answer is the closest! I came back to this problem and tried to edit your code for MySQL. Instead of return f"LOWER({rhs}) LIKE '%%' || LOWER({lhs}) || '%%'", params I now have return  "LOWER(%s) LIKE LOWER(%s)" % (rhs, lhs), params This works if I type a name that is identical to the one in the table. I need to add wildcard characters, but I keep getting errors every time I add them to this MySQL query.

Comment: I was able to figure the problem! See the answer below. Thank you so much for your help!